# Complex query to update a temp table. Possibly derived table or correlated sub query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that I am having a hard time wrapping my head around. I need to update a field in a temp table based upon the following conditions:

- I am getting the Leave Reason for an employee if they are currently on Leave
- An employee is considered on leave if the EmpSts is `On Leave`
- The Leave Reason is from the EmlChgRsn (Employment Change Reason) column, so if an employee is on leave the desired output will be either `FMLAFull Beg` or `FMLAInt Beg` in this instance
- The record where `EmlEfdDt IS NULL` is the most recent entry for that employee.
- Two different types of data scenarios are show below. The first image is the easy one--If `EmlEfdDt IS NULL and EmlSts = "On Leave" and EmlChgRsn LIKE '%FMLA%'`, then just display EmlChgRsn.
- The second image is the hard part--some adjustments to employment have been made since the employee went on leave, such as a supervisor change and salary change. I need to search up for the most recent EmlChgRsn that is related to leave-- `FMLAInt Beg` in this case.

the source data can look like the below:

[image]

OR

[image]

The final result, based upon sample data I have below, should look like this:
[image]

Below is some sample data to assist in figuring this out. Note on my first pass at getting the easy data in--Doesn't much matter if you do one or two passes or do something fancy to update it all in one go. I just need to get 'er done :) Thank you for your help!!

```
--Create temp table to update
CREATE TABLE #JobInfo (
 Emp varchar(10) NULL
,LeaveReason varchar(50) NULL
);
--Insert primer record with emp id's
INSERT INTO #JobInfo 
VALUES (3750, '')
  ,(3752, '')

--Create source data table
CREATE TABLE #Employment (
   Eml varchar(1) NULL
  ,EmlChgRsn varchar(50) NULL
  ,EmlEfdDt varchar(10) NULL
  ,Emp varchar(10) NULL
  ,EmpSts varchar(50) NULL
);

--Populate source data table with mock data
INSERT INTO #Employment
VALUES ('1', 'FMLAFull Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'TeamChange', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'FMLAInt Beg', NULL, '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'Active')
  ,('1', 'FMLAFull Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'New Supervisor', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'FMLAInt Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'New Supervisor', NULL, '3750', 'On Leave')

-- **First pass as updating the easy records
UPDATE #JobInfo
SET LeaveReason = (SELECT CASE WHEN (EmlChgRsn LIKE '%FMLA%Beg%' OR EmlChgRsn LIKE '%Leave%Beg%')
                            AND EmpSts = 'On Leave' THEN EmlChgRsn

                          ELSE '' END
                  FROM #Employment
                  WHERE #Employment.Emp = #JobInfo.Emp 
                    AND EmlEfdDt IS NULL
                    AND Eml = 1)

SELECT *
FROM #JobInfo                   
DROP TABLE #JobInfo
DROP TABLE #Employment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're after...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#JobInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #JobInfo;

CREATE TABLE #JobInfo (
     Emp varchar(10) NULL
    ,LeaveReason varchar(50) NULL
    );
--Insert primer record with emp id's
INSERT INTO #JobInfo VALUES (3750, ''), (3752, '');

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Employment', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #Employment;

CREATE TABLE #Employment (
   Eml varchar(1) NULL
  ,EmlChgRsn varchar(50) NULL
  ,EmlEfdDt varchar(10) NULL
  ,Emp varchar(10) NULL
  ,EmpSts varchar(50) NULL
    );

--Populate source data table with mock data
INSERT INTO #Employment
VALUES ('1', 'FMLAFull Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'TeamChange', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 101), '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'FMLAInt Beg', NULL, '3752', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -7, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'Active')
  ,('1', 'FMLAFull Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -6, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'Salary', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'New Supervisor', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'FMLAInt Beg', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()), 101), '3750', 'On Leave')
  ,('1', 'New Supervisor', NULL, '3750', 'On Leave');

--==============================================================================================

-- solution...
UPDATE ji SET 
    ji.LeaveReason = x.LeaveReason
FROM
    #JobInfo ji
    JOIN #Employment e1
        ON ji.Emp = e1.Emp
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CASE 
                                WHEN e1.EmlChgRsn LIKE 'FMLA%' 
                                THEN e1.EmlChgRsn
                                ELSE (
                                        SELECT TOP 1 
                                            e2.EmlChgRsn
                                        FROM 
                                            #Employment e2
                                        WHERE 
                                            e1.Emp = e2.Emp
                                            AND e2.EmlChgRsn LIKE 'FMLA%'
                                        ORDER BY 
                                            e2.EmlEfdDt DESC
                                        )
                        END) ) x (LeaveReason)
WHERE 
    e1.EmlEfdDt IS NULL
    AND e1.EmpSts = 'On Leave';

SELECT * FROM #JobInfo ji;
```

HTH, Jason

Comment: I see this gives the desired output. I am too tired to pick this apart to make sure it is what I need, but I'll get to this tomorrow morning and accept if it checks out. Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want the most recent occurrence of either fmlafull or fmlaint for any given employee?

```
SELECT a.Eml, a.EmlChgRsn as LeaveReason FROM (

  SELECT
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY eml ORDER BY COALESCE(EmlEfdDt, GetDate()) DESC) as rown 
  FROM
    employment t
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT eml FROM employment WHERE EmlEfdDt IS NULL and EmpSts = 'On Leave') a
    ON
      t.eml = a.eml
  WHERE
    EmlChgRsn IN ('FMLAFull Beg', 'FMLAInt Beg')
) a
WHERE
  a.rown = 1
```

We select only the fmla full or fmla int rows, we order them by descending order of date, giving any null a date of now as it would then surely be later (if it isn't, change the query to 100 years to now). We number the rows so the most recent in row 1, and then wrap it all in a query that selects only rows numbered 1. Partition is like groupby, the row numbering restarts from 1 for every unique eml id

If you're struggling with turning this into an update to change the jobinfo table, let me know... I think you'll be fine with that part though

Comment: I may have misread (it's 2:00 am here) but it's my impression that the most resent row, for a given emp (EmlEfdDt IS NULL), must have EmpSts = 'On Leave'... So it's not just a matter of finding the most resent  EmlChgRsn IN ('FMLAFull Beg', 'FMLAInt Beg')

Comment: Correct. If the most recent row has EmpSts of 'On Leave' , then they are currently on leave. If not, then I do not care about that emp right now.

Comment: I added an inner join to restrict the query to looking at only those employees currently on leave

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your input Caius! I'll check this out tomorrow. Too tired right now :)

Comment: I actually couldn't get this to work. Quite a few errors.